# How to set screen resolution in android emulator for a particular screen size..?

Tags: android, emulation

For example screen size is 7 inch. Now for a 7 inch screen, there can be different screen resolutions. So how to set a resolution of 480 * 800 for a 7 inch screen in emulator?
Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that while creating you Emulator.

[image]

Comment: And what about screen size..?

Comment: You can do that from next tab `Hardware`.

Comment: also you must set screen's density properly

Comment: What is screen's density..?
Kindly elaborate, I am new bee.

Comment: This should be a separate question. This link http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html may help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the emulator you can input the screen size which is diagnal lenght.  I use 6.  And then the resulation which I leave as defualt which is 96 I think.

Comment: I dont want to put default resolution, I want to fix the resolution to some specific vaules. How to do that..?